# Is Android driver implementation needed JNI or not?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, linux-device-driver

I'm using an application which needed driver utilities..For acheiving for this is JNI must or we can do it in any other option???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you will probably want to build a custom Kernel module to read the hardware and provide a standard interface.  You can get more details from the Android development site and should download the [Android Source here](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html)

If you are interfacing a USB device then check out the new USB development tools in the Android 3.1 SDK

Android JNI can be used,  but it is not as powerful as a kernel module.  However, you also don't need root to install it.  It really just depends on what type of hardware you are trying to support.